# How to programmatically(c#) get signature added online using Outlook Office 365

Tags: c#, outlook, office365, exchangewebservices

I have a text area in my C# MVC application where user can enter text which is used to create an email and send it to the recipient using Exchange Services. My requirement is to get the user's signature and pre-populate in the text area. 
How can I achieve this?

Update: I have received response from Microsoft Support team and here's the solution. It is possible to retrieve OWA signature programmatically. The signature created using Outlook installed on local system cannot be retrieved using EWS.

```
var rootFolder = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Root);
var owaConfig = UserConfiguration.Bind(service, "OWA.UserOptions", rootFolder.ParentFolderId, UserConfigurationProperties.All);

var signature = owaConfig.Dictionary["signaturehtml"];
```

Comment: Is your code running on a computer where Outlook is installed?

Comment: @Dmitry My code will be running on a web server. I know how to pick signatures for user for locally installed outlook but that will not help me in case of web server. It is easily possible that the signature was created in Office365.